# How do i stick content in between two other items using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am currently working on the design of user's post for my website. However, whenever the user uploads a video, it currently looks like this:

[image: Messed up image]

The post looks ugly and the video is placed inside of the yellow textbox, I wanna place it just below the yellow textbox. Here is an image showing where I would like the video to be placed (forgive me for the ugly handwriting):
[image: Image here]

And when the video is placed, I would like the content around it to be "pushed away" so they are not stuck on top of eachother.

Here is my code in question:

```
<Grid container item>
        <div id="post-container" style={{margin: '5%', position: 'absolute', width: '90%', height: '40%', backgroundColor: 'white', borderRadius: '30px', overflow: 'auto'}}>
          <Avatar src={<AvatarPicture/>} style={{position: 'absolute', left: '1%', top: '3%', height: '60px', width: '60px'}} size='lg'></Avatar>
          <p style={{position: 'absolute', left: '9%', top: '-5%', fontFamily: 'Outfit', fontStyle: 'normal', fontWeight: '500', fontSize: '20px', lineHeight: '25px', overflow: 'auto'}}>@{state.posts[i].username}</p>
          <p style={{position: 'absolute', left: '9%', top: '10%', fontFamily: 'Outfit', fontStyle: 'normal', fontWeight: '400', fontSize: '16px', lineHeight: '20px', color: '#6D7683'}}>{state.storage.location}</p>
          <p style={{position: 'absolute', left: '20%', top: '10%', fontFamily: 'Outfit', fontStyle: 'normal', fontWeight: '400', fontSize: '16px', lineHeight: '20px', color: '#2D87FF'}}>{state.posts[i].date}</p>
          <div id="text-container" style={{position: 'absolute', top: '30%', left: '5%', backgroundColor: '#FFFBEE', height: 'auto', width: '90%', borderRadius: '16px', overflowY: 'auto', overflowWrap: 'break-word', wordWrap: 'break-word', msWordBreak: 'break-word', wordBreak: 'break-word'}}><p style={{margin: '1em'}}>{state.posts[i].text}</p>{<ReactPlayer url={state.posts[i].video} />}</div>
          <TextField InputProps={{
            startAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment>
                <Avatar src={state.storage.profileImageURL} />
              </InputAdornment>
            ),
            classes: {
              notchedOutline: 'notched-outline-border-radius'
          }
          }} maxRows={10} inputProps={{maxLength: 500}} multiline style={{position: 'absolute', left: '5%', top: '78%', width: '90%', background: '#F8FAFF', border: '1px solid #D9E1F9', borderRadius: '16px'}} placeholder='Write your comment'></TextField>
          <IconButton onClick={() => handleLike(i)} style={{ position: 'absolute', top: '60%', left: '5%'}} onMouseLeave={() => setMouseOver(false)} onMouseOver={() => setMouseOver(true)}>{like[i] && mouseOver ? <HeartBrokenIcon style={{color: 'red'}}/> : like[i] ? <FavoriteIcon style={{color: 'red'}} /> : <FavoriteBorderTwoToneIcon /> }</IconButton>
          <p style={{position: 'absolute', top: '59%', left: '9%'}}>{state.posts[i].likes}</p>
          <IconButton onClick={() => handleReplies(i)} style={{ position: 'absolute', top: '60%', left: '13%'}}>{replies[i] ? <MessageIcon color="primary"/> : <MessageOutlinedIcon/>}</IconButton>
          <p style={{position: 'absolute', top: '59%', left: '17%'}}>{state.posts[i].comments}</p>
          <IconButton style={{ position: 'absolute', top: '60%', left: '23%'}}><IosShareOutlinedIcon /></IconButton>
          <p style={{position: 'absolute', top: '59%', left: '27%'}}>{state.posts[i].shares}</p>
        </div>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: Please post your rendered code (HTML/CSS) from the browser. As it is now, it's hard for us to begin helping you.

Comment: i used ```style``` for each component. I did not use a separate CSS file. If that is what you are asking...

Comment: You need to fix your style. Absolutely positioned elements will overlap each other. Use flexbox instead of absolutely positioned elements and percentages. Also, the video is currently inside `<div id="text-container">`. If you want to insert it below that, rewrite the JSX to match the structure you want.

Comment: @ChrisG Could u show me an example? please?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox

Comment: You seem to be using a layout library already, where is `Grid` coming from? Also note that in case you have multiple posts on a single page, `id="post-container"` produces invalid HTML. An `id` has to be unique

Comment: @ChrisG ```Grid``` is used to vertically line everything up

Comment: Is this Material UI?

Comment: yes it is Material UI

Comment: if i do flexbox, should i just make a div and place the flexbox properties inside there and then remove the percentages and ```absolute``` from the children?

Comment: Here's a proper Material UI Grid solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-silence-ct594g?file=/src/Post.js